# PHP+FastCGI+nginx on Debian

Tags: debian, php, nginx, fastcgi

I new with Debian. I want to use php on Debian. 
I do:

```
apt-get install php5-cli php5-cgi spawn-fcgi
```

Create file `/usr/bin/php-fastcgi`:

```
#! /bin/sh
PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=3
PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=1000
exec /usr/bin/php5-cgi
```

Create file `/etc/init.d/init-fastcgi`:

```
#!/bin/bash
PHP_SCRIPT="/usr/bin/spawn-fcgi -a 127.0.0.1 -p 9000 -u www-data -g www-data -f     /usr/bin/php-fastcgi"
RETVAL=0
case "$1" in
start)
$PHP_SCRIPT
RETVAL=$?
;;
stop)
killall -9 php5-cgi
RETVAL=$?
;;
restart)
killall -9 php5-cgi
$PHP_SCRIPT
RETVAL=$?
;;
*)
echo "Usage: sudo /etc/init.d/init-fastcgi {start|stop|restart}"
exit 1
;;
esac
exit $RETVAL
```

Ater do:

```
chmod 755 /usr/bin/php-fastcgi
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/init-fastcgi
```

Into `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` add:

```
location ~\.php$ {
 root /srv/www/ekb.mydomain.com/public_html;
 include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
 fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
 fastcgi_index index.php;
 fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/ekb.mydomain.com/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Create directories:

```
/srv/www/ekb.mydomain.com/public_html
/srv/www/ekb.mydomain.com/logs
```

Create file `/srv/www/ekb.mydomain.com/public_html/test.php`

```
<?phpinfo();?>
```

Start serice:

```
/etc/init.d/init-fastcgi start
/etc/init.d/nginx start
```

In browser:

```
 www.ekb.maydomain.com/test.php
```

but get 404 error.

What i can do wrong?

Comment: Go with `PHP-FPM` instead of `fastcgi` and use `unix-socket` instead of `localhost`.

Comment: +1. THere is no reason to do this instead of simply installing `php5-fpm` package.

Comment: nginx killing me.I war remove nginx,php5,php5-cgi and install it again, after do all configs from my question and php start to work. Magik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really configure nginx with php-fpm. It's easier to install, configure and manage and is as fast.

```
$ apt-get install nginx php5-fpm
$ nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

[...]
worker_processes  4;
[...]
keepalive_timeout   2;
[...]


$ nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

[...]
server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    location /doc/ {
            alias /usr/share/doc/;
            autoindex on;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            allow ::1;
            deny all;
    }

    # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
    #       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    #}

    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

            # With php5-cgi alone:
            #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            # With php5-fpm:
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

Start nginx and php-fpm:

```
$ service nginx start
$ service php5-fpm start
```

Comment: I try install php5-fpm but apt-get says that can't find this package.

Answer (score 1):

Try editing `/etc/hosts` and add to the localhost line as below:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost ekb.maydomain.com
```

In other words, add `ekb.maydomain.com` to whichever line begins `127.0.0.1` -- it may not look exactly like this one.

The problem is that "www.ekb.maydomain.com" is a real www address and the DNS resolver can't find it.  By adding that line to `/etc/hosts`, you skip DNS resolution for that domain and instead use it as an alias for `localhost`, which is where your browser can actually find a web server running on the same machine.